# The number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=51$ where $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ are odd natural numbers is?

Tags: combinatorics

> The number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=51$ where $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ are
>   odd natural numbers is?

MY APPROACH:I tried to solve it like coefficient of $t^{51}$ in $(t+t^3+t^5+...+t^{49})^3$.But it seems impossible to calculate it manually.Suggest me other approaches please!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We reduce the problem of solving the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 51$$ in the positive odd integers to determining the solution of an equation in the non-negative integers.  Let
\begin{align*}
x_1 & = 2y_1 + 1\\
x_2 & = 2y_2 + 1\\
x_3 & = 2y_3 + 1
\end{align*}
Then 
\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 & = 51\\
2y_1 + 1 + 2y_2 + 1 + 2y_3 + 1 & = 51\\
2y_1 + 2y_2 + 2y_3 & = 48\\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 & = 24
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the non-negative integers.  The number of solutions is the number of ways two addition signs can be inserted into a row of $24$ ones, which is $$\binom{24 + 2}{2}$$ since we must choose which two of the $26$ symbols ($24$ ones and $2$ addition signs) will be addition signs.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot.But one thing...was my approach right or wrong?

Comment: I am less familiar with generating functions than you are but, based on what I have seen, I believe your approach is correct.